# Mercurial Add On for Visual Studio not showing icons for 1 particular project

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial

I have a peculiar problem where all but 1 of my projects are showing the Mercurial plug-ins for my solution correctly.

All the projects have been committed in my mercurial repository already.

The icons for the problematic project actually shows up correctly in another solution that includes it.

Fixes I've tried so far:

1. Recreate the Solution file from scratch.
2. Remove/Add Project again.
3. File compared csproj & sln files between the working and non working solutions.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Has anyone come across this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to delete the hidden directories under the project folder that pertains to a different source control system (.svn).

It seems like the Mercurial add-on and/or Visual Studio gets confused if it sees more than 1 hidden folders under the project directory.